# If a value then return another value in a new column in R

Tags: r, if-statement, categories

I have a data set that has several columns. One of the columns is called "group" and has values like: 1124,1251,2615,3541. I want to insert a new column that looks at the value in a row in "group" and returns a category name. So, 1124 would return "Test" and 1251 would return "Coffee."

Comment: What about cases that are neither '1124' or '1251'?

Comment: Read `?match` (help page)

Comment: [This page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1088/creating-vectors#t=201702212027309249265) in SO Documentation should also be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
df$Category <- NA
df$Category[df$Group==1124] <- "Test"
df$Category[df$Group==1251] <- "Coffee"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a combination of mutate and ifelse:

df %>% dplyr::mutate(Category = ifelse(Group == 1124, "Test", "NA"))%>%#this creates a new column called Category that will have an entry of Test if Group is equal to 1124. If this condition is not satisfied, the appropriate row in the Category column will be NA
dplyr::mutate(Category = ifelse(Group == 1251, "Coffee", Category))#this will fill the Category column with an entry of Coffee if Group is equal to 1251. If this condition is not satisfied, the appropriate row in the Category column will remain what it currently is

If you would instead prefer the entry in the Category column to be a blank and not an NA, replace the "NA" term with "".